# Power Apps: After Patch, text field is the only thing visible and no item is selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a gallery on the left to display a filtered list of items.  I have a gallery on the right to display the details of the selected item.

Also on the right, I have a text field and a save button.  The button Patches and saves correctly, but if I go to a success screen on save and go back, there are is no item selected so the right gallery is empty except the text field and save button.

What I can't seem to get working is to either hide the text field and button until an item is selected or to select the first record on navigation back from the success screen.

This seems like it would be easy (to me), but I'm having a bugger of a time.

So either have an empty gallery on the right or to select the first item in the left gallery:

[image: So either have an empty gallery on the right or to select the first item in the left gallery]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the text input and button control, try setting `Visible` property of text input and button control to:

```
!IsBlank(Gallery1.Selected)
```

OR

```
!IsBlankOrError(Gallery1.Selected)
```

Where `Gallery1` is name of gallery control on left side.

Comment: I think I had tried something similar, but didn't get it quite right.  That'll do, thanks for the help!